# How to sum multiple rows into 1 group in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm doing export but don't know how to `foreach` calculate
get the employee's total time worked and how much the total amount.

data is retrieved from the database

[image]

```
$data = Clocks::orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->get();
$row = [];
    foreach ($data as $index) {
        $row[] = array(
            '0' => $index->user_id,
            '1' => $index->total_time,
            '2' => $index->earned_amount,
            '3' => $index->bonus_pay,
        );
    }
return (collect($row));
```

I want to output it like this

```
user    time    amount  bonus
1       25:30   400     20
3       9:00    150
```

Please help me, thank you for viewing this article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way

```
$data = Clocks::groupBy('user_id')
        ->selectRaw('SEC_TO_TIME( SUM(time_to_sec(`total_time`)))  as total_time,
                            SUM(`earned_amount`) as earned_amount,
                            SUM(`bonus_pay`) as bonus_pay, user_id')
        ->get();
```